# Hypothesis test for difference in preference pre and post treatment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, references

Two large beach holiday destinations near Bangkok, Thailand are Pattaya and Hua Hin. In a random sample of 100 individuals in Bangkok who have been on a weekend away to nearby beach destinations 6 preferred Pattaya and  3 preferred Hua Hin. The other 91 did not have a preference. These individuals were then exposed to certain tourism promotional material and after such exposure 12 preferred Pattaya and 1 preferred Hua Hin. The remaining 87 had no preference. I would like to set up a hypothesis test to determine if the promotional material had an effect on preference. Your assistance or a referral to a URL for a tutorial on this kind of hypothesis testing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @Cha-am Jamal, but we treat them differently (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Please tell us what you understand & have tried already, & we'll provide some hints to help get you unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a chi-squared Test of independence test, but you will face an issue with the fact that only 1 respondent has chosen Hua Hin post receiving a stimulus.

Your alternative would be to run a Fisher's exact test to accommodate less than a frequency of 5 in each cell.

Note: Since your samples are paired, you would want to use a McNemar test instead.